# $_GET[] não funciona

Tags: php

Tenho uma página `.onion` hospedada por Freedom, no qual suporta PHP 5, estou tentando carregar a página inicial do site `home.html` a partir do "loader" `index.php`, no qual tem esse início no código:

```
<?php
   $get = $_GET['load'];
   if(strpos($_GET['load'],'/language/') !== false) {
     $loadurl = file_get_contents("home.html");
     echo($loadurl);
     exit;
  }
```

aí quando vou entrar no site, é isso que aparece no início da página e ela não é exibida corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ambos arquivos estão na raiz do diretório da hospedagem. como solucionar essas mensagens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa usar `isset` para checar se o get possui o índice.

```
   if( isset( $_GET['load'] ) )
   {
       if( strpos( $_GET['load'] , '/language/' ) !== false )
       {
         $loadurl = file_get_contents("home.html");
         echo($loadurl);
         exit;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente passar a variavel load como parametro na sua url

```
index.php?load=VALOR
```